# Update Compose vendor folder on docker volume for later usage

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php, volume

I build my PHP image with composer dependencies using multistage Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM composer AS vendor
WORKDIR /app

COPY composer.json .
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-ansi --no-dev --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader

FROM alpine:3.16
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apk add --no-cache \
php8 \
php8-fpm \
php8-mbstring \
php8-pdo_mysql \
php8-exif \
php8-pcntl \
php8-bcmath \
php8-gd \
php8-soap \
php8-zip \
php8-sockets \
php8-session \
php8-fileinfo

RUN \
addgroup -g 82 -S www-data || true && \
adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data || true && \
sed -i '/listen = /c listen = 0.0.0.0:9000' /etc/php8/php-fpm.d/www.conf && \
chown -R 82: /var/log/php*

COPY --chown=82:82 --from=vendor /app/vendor ./vendor
COPY --chown=82:82 . .

EXPOSE 9000

USER 82

CMD ["php-fpm8", "-F"]
```

Works great, but the vendor folder is nearly 90 MB out of 115, which is quite an enormous size for a container.

```bash
/var/www/html $ du -shd 1
1.5M    ./resources
2.6M    ./app
16.0K   ./docker-compose
8.0K    ./mysql
20.0K   ./nginx
11.0M   ./storage
28.0K   ./tests
16.0K   ./bootstrap
9.2M    ./.git
156.0K  ./config
1.8M    ./public
340.0K  ./database
32.0K   ./routes
88.4M   ./vendor
115.3M  .
```

Furthermore, I need to use the same PHP image for listening rabbitmq queues (more than 20) so that'd be great to reduce container's size.
I'd like to mount the vendor folder as volume on host and update files there every time when composer is kicked off.
So, Dockerfile should be splitted up - composer create/update content of the vendor folder on volume and PHP containers just use that volume.
Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do it.
Is it possible without rsync crutch from $COMPOSER_HOME/vendor to volume?

Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM composer

RUN install -d -m 755 -o 82 -g 82 /vendor

USER 82

WORKDIR /vendor

COPY composer.json .

#ENV COMPOSER=/vendor/composer.json
#ENV COMPOSER_HOME=/app/home

CMD ["composer", "install", "--ignore-platform-reqs", "--no-ansi", "--no-dev", "--no-interaction", "--no-progress", "--no-scripts", "--optimize-autoloader"]
```

Build:

```bash
$ docker build -f Dockerfile-composer -t lk/composer .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  25.36MB
Step 1/6 : FROM composer
 ---> 62036ae50a68
Step 2/6 : RUN install -d -m 755 -o 82 -g 82 /vendor
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3b34fcac49a9
Step 3/6 : USER 82
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4cef45b90fb2
Step 4/6 : WORKDIR /vendor
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c1a2a86d5ee
Step 5/6 : COPY composer.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c65d78bbb9e6
Step 6/6 : CMD composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --no-ansi --no-dev --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader
 ---> Running in eb30c82c27dc
Removing intermediate container eb30c82c27dc
 ---> e19ce1f91970
Successfully built e19ce1f91970
Successfully tagged lk/composer:latest
```

Run:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -it -v /docker/lk/www/vendor:/vendor/vendor lk/composer

No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 155 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking asm89/stack-cors (v2.1.1)
  - Locking barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (v1.0.2)
  - Locking beyondcode/laravel-websockets (1.14.0)
  - Locking brick/math (0.11.0)
  - Locking bschmitt/laravel-amqp (2.1.2)
  - Locking cboden/ratchet (v0.4.4)
  - Locking composer/semver (3.3.2)
  - Locking darkaonline/l5-swagger (8.5.1)
  - Locking dflydev/dot-access-data (v3.0.2)
  - Locking doctrine/annotations (1.14.3)
  - Locking doctrine/cache (2.2.0)
  - Locking doctrine/dbal (3.6.3)
  - Locking doctrine/deprecations (v1.1.1)
  - Locking doctrine/event-manager (2.0.0)
  - Locking doctrine/inflector (2.0.6)
  - Locking doctrine/instantiator (2.0.0)
  - Locking doctrine/lexer (1.2.3)
  - Locking dompdf/dompdf (v1.2.2)
  - Locking dragonmantank/cron-expression (v3.3.2)
  - Locking egulias/email-validator (2.1.25)
  - Locking evenement/evenement (v3.0.1)
  - Locking ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.16.0)
  - Locking facade/flare-client-php (1.10.0)
  - Locking facade/ignition (2.17.7)
  - Locking facade/ignition-contracts (1.0.2)
  - Locking fakerphp/faker (v1.22.0)
  - Locking fig/http-message-util (1.1.5)
  - Locking filp/whoops (2.15.2)
  - Locking fruitcake/laravel-cors (v2.2.0)
  - Locking graham-campbell/result-type (v1.1.1)
  - Locking guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.7.0)
  - Locking guzzlehttp/promises (2.0.0)
  - Locking guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.5.0)
  - Locking hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1)
  - Locking intervention/image (2.7.2)
  - Locking laravel/framework (v8.83.27)
  - Locking laravel/sail (v1.22.0)
  - Locking laravel/sanctum (v2.15.1)
  - Locking laravel/serializable-closure (v1.3.0)
  - Locking laravel/telescope (v4.14.6)
  - Locking laravel/tinker (v2.8.1)
  - Locking league/commonmark (2.4.0)
  - Locking league/config (v1.2.0)
  - Locking league/flysystem (1.1.10)
  - Locking league/mime-type-detection (1.11.0)
  - Locking maatwebsite/excel (3.1.48)
  - Locking maennchen/zipstream-php (v2.4.0)
  - Locking markbaker/complex (3.0.2)
  - Locking markbaker/matrix (3.0.1)
  - Locking milon/barcode (9.0.1)
  - Locking mockery/mockery (1.6.2)
  - Locking monolog/monolog (2.9.1)
  - Locking myclabs/deep-copy (1.11.1)
  - Locking myclabs/php-enum (1.8.4)
  - Locking nesbot/carbon (2.67.0)
  - Locking nette/schema (v1.2.3)
  - Locking nette/utils (v4.0.0)
  - Locking nikic/php-parser (v4.15.5)
  - Locking nunomaduro/collision (v5.11.0)
  - Locking opis/closure (3.6.3)
  - Locking paragonie/constant_time_encoding (v2.6.3)
  - Locking paragonie/random_compat (v9.99.100)
  - Locking paragonie/sodium_compat (v1.20.0)
  - Locking phar-io/manifest (2.0.3)
  - Locking phar-io/version (3.2.1)
  - Locking phenx/php-font-lib (0.5.4)
  - Locking phenx/php-svg-lib (0.4.1)
  - Locking php-amqplib/php-amqplib (v3.5.3)
  - Locking phpoffice/phpspreadsheet (1.28.0)
  - Locking phpoption/phpoption (1.9.1)
  - Locking phpseclib/phpseclib (3.0.19)
  - Locking phpunit/php-code-coverage (9.2.26)
  - Locking phpunit/php-file-iterator (3.0.6)
  - Locking phpunit/php-invoker (3.1.1)
  - Locking phpunit/php-text-template (2.0.4)
  - Locking phpunit/php-timer (5.0.3)
  - Locking phpunit/phpunit (9.6.8)
  - Locking psr/cache (3.0.0)
  - Locking psr/container (1.1.2)
  - Locking psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0)
  - Locking psr/http-client (1.0.2)
  - Locking psr/http-factory (1.0.2)
  - Locking psr/http-message (1.1)
  - Locking psr/log (2.0.0)
  - Locking psr/simple-cache (1.0.1)
  - Locking psy/psysh (v0.11.18)
  - Locking pusher/pusher-php-server (7.2.3)
  - Locking ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3)
  - Locking ramsey/collection (2.0.0)
  - Locking ramsey/uuid (4.7.4)
  - Locking ratchet/rfc6455 (v0.3.1)
  - Locking react/cache (v1.2.0)
  - Locking react/dns (v1.11.0)
  - Locking react/event-loop (v1.4.0)
  - Locking react/http (v1.9.0)
  - Locking react/promise (v2.10.0)
  - Locking react/socket (v1.13.0)
  - Locking react/stream (v1.2.0)
  - Locking ringcentral/psr7 (1.3.0)
  - Locking sabberworm/php-css-parser (8.4.0)
  - Locking sebastian/cli-parser (1.0.1)
  - Locking sebastian/code-unit (1.0.8)
  - Locking sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (2.0.3)
  - Locking sebastian/comparator (4.0.8)
  - Locking sebastian/complexity (2.0.2)
  - Locking sebastian/diff (4.0.5)
  - Locking sebastian/environment (5.1.5)
  - Locking sebastian/exporter (4.0.5)
  - Locking sebastian/global-state (5.0.5)
  - Locking sebastian/lines-of-code (1.0.3)
  - Locking sebastian/object-enumerator (4.0.4)
  - Locking sebastian/object-reflector (2.0.4)
  - Locking sebastian/recursion-context (4.0.5)
  - Locking sebastian/resource-operations (3.0.3)
  - Locking sebastian/type (3.2.1)
  - Locking sebastian/version (3.0.2)
  - Locking spatie/laravel-permission (5.10.1)
  - Locking spatie/laravel-welcome-notification (2.3.2)
  - Locking swagger-api/swagger-ui (v4.19.0)
  - Locking swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.3.0)
  - Locking symfony/console (v5.4.24)
  - Locking symfony/css-selector (v6.3.0)
  - Locking symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.3.0)
  - Locking symfony/error-handler (v5.4.24)
  - Locking symfony/event-dispatcher (v6.3.0)
  - Locking symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.3.0)
  - Locking symfony/finder (v5.4.21)
  - Locking symfony/http-foundation (v5.4.24)
  - Locking symfony/http-kernel (v5.4.24)
  - Locking symfony/mime (v5.4.23)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.27.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.27.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.27.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.27.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.27.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.27.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.27.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.27.0)
  - Locking symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.27.0)
  - Locking symfony/process (v5.4.24)
  - Locking symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.2.0)
  - Locking symfony/routing (v5.4.22)
  - Locking symfony/service-contracts (v2.5.2)
  - Locking symfony/string (v6.3.0)
  - Locking symfony/translation (v6.3.0)
  - Locking symfony/translation-contracts (v3.3.0)
  - Locking symfony/var-dumper (v5.4.24)
  - Locking symfony/yaml (v6.3.0)
  - Locking theseer/tokenizer (1.2.1)
  - Locking tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.6)
  - Locking vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq (v11.3.0)
  - Locking vlucas/phpdotenv (v5.5.0)
  - Locking voku/portable-ascii (1.6.1)
  - Locking webmozart/assert (1.11.0)
  - Locking zircote/swagger-php (4.7.10)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file
Package operations: 120 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

In Filesystem.php line 254:

  /vendor/vendor/voku does not exist and could not be created.


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--download-only] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [--audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]
```

Comment: Your code should be completely contained in an image – I would not recommend trying to split off your library dependencies into a volume that needs to be separately maintained.  If you just need to run multiple containers off the same code base, you can override the command when you run the RabbitMQ listener but use the same image, and it won't require any additional space.

Comment: "which is quite an enormous size for a container" - is it? With that many packages, that looks pretty common. Why not try to reduce the amount of packages that you've installed? If you just want to listen for queueing stuff, you most probably don't need PHPUnit installed in that container

Comment: @DavidMaze, so the size of the image doesn't affect resource consumption? I simply try to make the smallest containers which can start quickly.

Comment: @NicoHaase, the funny thing that I'm not a programmer, I'm just trying to move to docker the project that our developers wrote. So I don't know which packages are not needed... PHP unit isn't needed if I listen queue? That's how command looks like (got from supervisor configs):
/usr/bin/php /var/www/site/artisan queue:work --queue=lk.job.schedule
/usr/bin/php /var/www/site/artisan rabbitmq:consume-manager-image

Comment: Usually, PHPUnit shouldn't be installed in **any** production environment